# GCM registration token regenerates frequenty

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging

I have following code for to obtain GCM registration token :

```
gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
```

Now from the official documentation device token changes in following cases :

1. App deletes Instance ID
2. Device is factory reset
3. User uninstalls the app
4. User clears app data

Now in my case When I put the device in **power mode** for more the an hour and switch back to normal mode again I receive a new registration token. Why is this happening?

```
I am using following Device : 
Samsung Galaxy Note 9
Android Version 9
one UI version 1.0
```

[I am working on migrating to FCM]

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `onHandleIntent` method of `RegistrationIntentService` class which extends `IntentService`

```
try {        
    InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
    String token = instanceID.getToken("<your sender id>",
            GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);

    Log.i(TAG, "GCM Registration Token: " + token);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Failed to complete token refresh", e);
}
```